# flask/gunicron not letting me upload large files

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have allowed user to upload file size around 20 MB. I create limit on javascript using following code

```
 if(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob){
    var total_files_size = 0;
    if(this.elements['file_attach[]'].files.length > maximum_files){
                alert( "Can not select more than "+maximum_files+" file(s)");
                proceed = false;
            }


   $(this.elements['file_attach[]'].files).each(function(i, ifile){
       if(ifile.value !== ""){ //continue only if file(s) are selected
           if(allowed_file_types.indexOf(ifile.type) === -1){ //check unsupported file
                        alert( ifile.name + " is unsupported file type!");
                        proceed = false;
                    }
                 total_files_size = total_files_size + ifile.size; //add file size to total size
                }
            });


 if(total_files_size > allowed_file_size){
                alert( "Make sure total file size is less than 20 MB!");
                proceed = false;
            }
```

Then I used max_content_length to increase size as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 21 * 1024 * 1024
```

It works locally just fine when I run my app without gunicron. However, it doesn't work when I deployed in server.

my gunicorn system file as below

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target network-online.target multi-user.target

[Service]
User=xxx
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/flask_app
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/flask_app/flask_app_env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/flask_app/flask_env/bin/gunicorn --workers 6 --bind unix:contact_form.sock -m 007 --max-requests 100 wsgi:app
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target network-online.target
```

any help is appericated

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy with gunicorn (eg nginx)? What error are you getting?

Comment: I have updated code